# How do I read specific csv file into pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm having a problem reading the file titanic.csv into a pandas dataframe. The csv is delimited by `","`, but when I try to read into pandas with the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("titanic_train.csv")
df.head()
```

I get an issue with all values ending up in the first column. I tried to add `delimiter=","` in the read command, but still no luck.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?
Thanks a lot!

[image: Df when printing .head()]

Comment: Can you please add here the first lines of this titanic.csv?

Comment: From the pandas docs, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html, delimiter is an alias for sep, and sep is "," by default.

Comment: Here is the column row + the first row of the csv: / PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked /
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("titanic_train.csv",sep=",")

Comment: Looks like you need to escape quote chars `pd.read_csv(...., escape='"')`

Comment: I can't see any obvious reason why your code shouldn't work... Could you link to the exact file you are trying to read? There seems to be a few files named titanic_train.csv scattered around the web...

Answer (score -1):

Like others mentioned, a simple read_csv should have worked for you.

Here are few ways to debug:

1. You can run the all-inclusive code below and see if it functions.
2. You can copy paste the included string in a text file and try to load it.
3. You can use an online python editor e.g. google colab, to ensure that its not related to your local setup.
4. You can post the link to csv to get further help.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

sample=StringIO('''PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
8,0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard",male,2,3,1,349909,21.075,,S
9,1,3,"Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)",female,27,0,2,347742,11.1333,,S
''')

df = pd.read_csv(sample)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass  ...     Fare Cabin  Embarked
0            1         0       3  ...   7.2500   NaN         S
1            2         1       1  ...  71.2833   C85         C
2            3         1       3  ...   7.9250   NaN         S
3            4         1       1  ...  53.1000  C123         S
4            5         0       3  ...   8.0500   NaN         S
5            6         0       3  ...   8.4583   NaN         Q
```